# Storing pass/fail result after all tests are run

Tags: python, pytest

I am relatively new to `pytest` at the moment and was curious if there is a way to store the pass/fail results of the test in a variable.

Essentially what I want to do is run my full suite of tests and after the tests are run, send the name of the tests run along with the pass/fail result to a server.

I understand that `pytest` provides options such as `-r` that will output the test run with pass or fail after execution, but is there a way to store those into variables or pass those results along?

Comment: Do you have any code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: So far, I can use request.node.name to find out the names of the test cases being run, but the issue is gathering the pass/fail and storing that into a variable

Comment: variable of what? python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to store those into variables or pass those results along?

Pytest can natively [output JUnitXML files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files):

> To create result files which can be read by [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or other Continuous integration servers, use this invocation:
>
> ```
> pytest --junitxml=path
> ```
>
> to create an XML file at `path`.

There is an available [schema](https://github.com/windyroad/JUnit-Schema) for this format and there appear to be several Python libraries that can parse them with varying levels of support. [This one](https://pypi.org/project/junitparser/) looks like a good place to start.

There are also plugins that may be able to help. For example, [`pytest-json`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json/):

> pytest-json is a plugin for [py.test](http://pytest.org/) that generates JSON reports for test results